# Compute 15 rows in parallel (through vectorization) and create df with them

Tags: r, lapply

I am creating 15 rows in a dataframe, like this. I cannot show my real code, but the create row function involves complex calculations that can be put in a function. Any ideas on how I can do this using lapply, apply, etc. to create all 15 in parallel and then concatenate all the rows into a dataframe? I think using lapply will work (i.e. put all rows in a list, then unlist and concatenate, but not exactly sure how to do it).

```
for( i in 1:15 ) {
    row <- create_row()
    # row is essentially a dataframe with 1 row
    rbind(my_df,row)
}
```

Comment: Use `mcmapply` on that function and then `bind_rows` on the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you,

```
create_row <- function(){
  rnorm(10, 0,1)
}

my_list <- vector(100, mode = "list")
my_list_2 <- lapply(my_list, function(x) create_row())
data.frame(t(sapply(my_list_2,c)))
```

The `create_row` function is just make the example reproducible, then we predefine an empty list, then fill it with the result from the `create_row()` function, then convert the resulting list to a data frame.

Alternatively, predefine a matrix and use the `apply` functions, over the row margin, then use the `t` (transpose) function, to get the output correct,

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 100))
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) create_row(x)))
```